Power Automate help to understand get item query
I'm a noob to Power automate,(Flow). Something like,  "When an existing item is modified", then "get items" (Get dummy column OldID data from another Sharepoint list, that matches the Sharepoint ID from "When an existing item is modified"). Using the "get item" (sharepoint list column OldID data to then get the new ID assigned upon import. Finally, parallel branch to update items in both lists.
Objective is to "update item" into an imported Sharepoint list from excel. The problem is when the Sharepoint list was imported the loss of ID, created and modified columns were stripped upon import and needed to creat dummy columns to retain data.
I don't understand how to construct the filter query to meet my objective.
Thx


Try this Filter Query link and let me know if you have any questions. There are many other online help as well
